# Deploying Spinnaker to Openshift fails at spin-redis-bootstrap stage

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, spinnaker

I'm trying to deploy Spinnaker into an Openshift cluster(v3.10) using Halyard. Everything seems to deploy OK up until the deployment of `spin-redis-bootstrap`. The `hal deploy apply` command eventually times out, with the following error in the `spin-redis-bootstrap` pod logs:

```
Redis master data doesn't exist, data won't be persistent!
mkdir: cannot create directory '/redis-master-data': Permission denied
[7] 01 Oct 17:21:04.443 # Can't chdir to '/redis-master-data': No such file or directory
```

Seems like a permissions issue. This error does not occur when deploying directly to Kubernetes(v1.10).

Does halyard use a specific service account to deploy the Spinnaker services, that I would need to grant additional permissions to?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is your Kubernetes deployment different from your Openshift deployment?

Comment: No different. Both Kubernetes versions are the same - 1.10 (Openshift is 3.10)

Comment: We have the exact same problem with OpenShift 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to spin Redis for Spinnaker by changing Docker image to **registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/redis-32-rhel7** in deployment config.

The reason it was failing due to more strictly permissions in OpenShift.